# File Path in C++ Assert not found on my disk

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual C++ to build a dll with some open source projects, but when I got an error, it read:

[image]

How did the "f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\vsprintf.c" come out? I even didn't have a "f" disk. I've searched around about my source code, and there is no such string.

Any idea about this?

Comment: That filename/linenumber information was baked into the CRT DLL by Microsoft, when they were building it. It's based on the filepaths Microsoft engineers were using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file path as @Dcoder says is not from your disk.

This message is from the CRT (C run time library) that you link with your programs. MSVCRT.DLL (or a version of it)

When Microsoft wrote their source code to create this library they built special code called [Assertions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) into it. This code (when you link to debug version of the library) checks the parameters that you sent to a function in the library, and passes helpful messages to you.

In this case you've called a function like `printf` or `sprintf` etc, and that eventually went into a piece of Microsoft function that lives in a microsoft file called `vsprintf.c`.

This file when the library was compiled inside Microsoft, it was done on the F: drive INSIDE Microsoft . It doesn't live on your disk.

Edit: if you add your code to your question we can help you find where this occurred.

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated in comments, the path described in the assertion dialog is the path of the source file that threw the assertion. In this case, a CRT `sprintf` function threw an assert.

The 'f:...' path doesn't refer to a path on your own machine: it's the path to the source file on the machine that compiled the file into the CRT DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a debug assertion failure - you apparently passed a `NULL`-value to a function of the `sprintf`-family.
You should check your source-code for any `NULL`-values you pass to such a function.

Comment: I know it's an error but my question is the 'file path', I don't have a 'f' disk

Answer (score -1):

It's where the Common Run Time (CRT) framework is installed. vsprintf.c is part of the CRT and something in that DLL has called one of the sprintf() functions with a null format string.

Comment: But I don't have a 'f' disk, not to mention the 'dd\vctools' blah blah

Comment: Nope. It's where Microsoft's build system keeps the source code. The value of `__FILE__` was baked into the assertion when the DLL was built.